# what does the width parameter of function __shfl_up(int var, unsigned int delta, int width) mean?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

What does the width parameter in `__shfl_up(int var, unsigned int delta, int width = warpSize)` mean? 
Assuming that `var equals 4` in lane 4 and `var equals 8` in lane 8. if I call `__shfl_up(var, 4, 8)` in lane 8, what it is returning?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/) and [this](http://acceleware.com/blog/keplers-shuffle-instruction) article.

Comment: I'v got the answer. The width divides the warp into 32/width partitions and each has width elements. the 8th lane call __shfl_up(var, 4, 8) is similar with the first lane's call. therefore __shfl_up(var,4,8) called by the 8th lane returns the 8th lane's var itself. Thanks!

Comment: How about if someone posts an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width parameter divides warpSize(typically 32) into partitions and each has width elements. Let's suppose the caller's warp id is laneId. calling __shfl_up(var, offset, width) will calculate source lane id, srclaneId = (laneId % width) - offset. if srclaneId is between 0 and width-1(inclusive) and the thread of srclaneId is active(see [Active thread in a warp](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture__notes)), __shfl_up(var, offset, width) returns the value of srclaneId's var, otherwise returns the value of laneid's var. In addition width must be power-of-2 (i.e. 2, 4, 8, 16 or 32).